# AngularJS - ng-grid data does not display on column resizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm facing an issue where ng-grid data does not display on column resizing, when column names change.

Created a plunkr at -
http://plnkr.co/edit/eV9baoDOV9A46FZmKW8G?p=preview

Please note the below function in main.js to explicitly change the column names and corresponding data.

```
$scope.reload = function(){
  $scope.columnDefinitions = [
      {field: 'first_col'},
      {field: 'second_col'}
    ];

  $scope.myData = [{first_col: "colData1", second_col: "colData2"},
                  {first_col: "colData3", second_col: "colData4"},
                  {first_col: "colData5", second_col: "colData6"}
                ];  
}
```

Steps -

**Scenario 1 (works)**.

1. Once the example fully loads including data from ng-grid, click on the "change" button.
2. With that, the "name" and "age" columns will change to "first_col" and "second_col" along with corresponding data.

**Scenario 2 (doesn't work)**

1. Rerun the example.
2. Once the example fully loads including data from ng-grid, resize the columns a bit.
3. After resizing, click the "change" button.
4. The grid now shows up as empty.

Really stuck with this issue. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Saw the issue before, cannot reproduce it anymore for some reason. I also tried on JSBin, and it just works for me now. Did you have the issue locally or was it on plunkr only ?

Comment: I have this issue locally as well. Been struggling with it for a while now. I'm using "ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js". Is this different from what you have?

Comment: Nvm, I thought you meant ticking off a column by resizing (that was also triggering a similar issue for me, earlier). I do get the error too.

Comment: NP. Thanks for letting me know. BTW, do you know if there is any way I can reinitialize ng-grid on demand (in my case if the column names change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the width of the column is not getting picked up when you press change. If you [manually define it](http://plnkr.co/edit/TWPugL0vwOOvz897FHUo?p=preview), it will work :

```
{field: 'first_col', width: 200},
{field: 'second_col', width: 200}
```

From the [ng-grid documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns) :

> Width can also be defined in percentages (20%, 30%), in weighted *s, or "auto" (which sizes the column based on data length) (much like WPF/Silverlight)/ **note: "auto" only works in single page apps currently because the re-size happens on "document.ready". Still working on improving that**.

So I'm guessing it's defaulting on "auto" and that's why it's not working. If you try putting "auto" (or anything %-based) as width, you'll also get the error. 
I suggest you use a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: You may have another problem with the sorting btw. If you try sorting before changing, you'll see some fun results.